# How to remove rel="canonical" from Wordpress Yoast plugin?

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I have the following url structure: An article is split into 4 parts as so:

```
example.com/article/
example.com/article/?page=2
example.com/article/?page=3
example.com/article/?page=4
```

I noticed that whenever I have the URL parameter, the result has a canonical link `<link rel="canonical" href="example.com/article"/>`

I don't know why this is generated, this is not in my template, nor I've specified it in the yoast settings. Is it possible to remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoast plugin has its own filter which ads that canonical link to wp header. to disable it try this in your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Hey - thank you for contributing to SO.  As a steward of StackOverflow, in the future you might consider flagging the question as duplicate rather than answering a duplicate question. (This is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529409/removing-rel-canonical-added-by-yoast-seo-plugin)