# In Wordpress, How to get the canonical URL which should be same as main URL which we can see in browser toolbar?

Tags: wordpress, canonical-link, trailing-slash

I'm using wordpress platform for my website. And I'm using custom-permalink plugin for url customization.Now,how can I get that customized url as canonical url without trailing slash issue?
Sample links are mentioned below.

https://www.drona.in

https://www.drona.in/govt-jobs/karnataka/haveri-district-court-recruitment-notification

If you see canonical URL for given second URL above,the extra slash is added at the end.

Now I want whichever URL is present for a post,the same URL should come as canonical URL.

Thanks in Advance.

I have already tried with Yoast settings, permalinks settings.
And I'm using Thesis theme.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for dynamic canonical URL.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.yourdomain.com<?php echo 
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>">
```

Try this function

```
function wpse_302620_canonical_url( $canonical_url, $post ) {
if ( $post->ID === 1234 ) {
    $canonical_url = 'https://www.examplesite.com/my-guest-post';
} 

return $canonical_url;
}
add_filter( 'get_canonical_url', 'wpse_302620_canonical_url', 10, 2 );
```

Hope its working for you

Comment: I'm using Thesis theme,Its not like all the themes and doesnt have header.php,footer.php etc

Comment: Try this function 
function wpse_302620_canonical_url( $canonical_url, $post ) {
    if ( $post->ID === 1234 ) {
        $canonical_url = 'https://www.examplesite.com/my-guest-post';
    } 

    return $canonical_url;
}
add_filter( 'get_canonical_url', 'wpse_302620_canonical_url', 10, 2 );

Comment: Where should I add this wpse_302620_canonical_url()?

Comment: In Function file

Comment: I'm using thesis theme...There is no functions.php file
http://diythemes.com/thesis/

Comment: You have only admin section access?

Comment: I'm having FTP access too...
Do you know thesis theme files structure?

Comment: Now I can add a canonical tag from functions.php.
But I want to remove previous existed(default) canonical tag.
I tried with add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', '__return_false' ); and also I tried with  remove_action('wp_head', 'rel_canonical'); But not working. I'm using Yoast SEO plugin.

Comment: Try this function remove_canonical() {
    add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', '__return_false',  10, 1 );
}
add_action('wp', 'remove_canonical');  can you vote up for my answer for other help

Comment: Yeah,I tried with this also.
I saw it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529409/removing-rel-canonical-added-by-yoast-seo-plugin